# How can I select data using Ruby and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse data from XML. This is an exerpt from the data file:

```
 <table>
               <tr>
                    <th class="indent normal">Profit and loss account</th>
                    <td class="notefigure"></td>
                    <td id="currentProfitAndLossAccount" class="figure">
                (<ix:nonFraction name="uk-gaap-pt:ProfitLossAccountReserve" contextRef="current-mud" unitRef="currencyUnit" format="ixt:numdotdecimal" decimals="0" sign="-" >12,345</ix:nonFraction><span class="endnegmark">)</span>
              </td>
                    <td id="previousProfitAndLossAccount" class="figure">
                        (<ix:nonFraction name="uk-gaap-pt:ProfitLossAccountReserve" contextRef="previous-mud" unitRef="currencyUnit" format="ixt:numdotdecimal" decimals="0" sign="-" >67,890</ix:nonFraction><span class="endnegmark">)</span>
                        </td>
             </tr>
 </table>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'JSON'
require 'Pry'
require 'csv'

# this is how we request the page we're going to scrape
page = File.open("D:/accounts_file.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

#this is the empty array to store the output
companies_array = []

# this is where the data is parsed

page.css('table').css('th').map do |a|
    post_name = a.text
    companies_array.push(post_name)
end

page.css('table').css('td').map do |a|
    post_name = a.text
    companies_array.push(post_name)
end

# this pushes the data into the .csv file
CSV.open('D:/financial_data','w') do |csv|
    csv << companies_array
end
```

At the moment, I get a table header row, followed by table content, but it does not line up with the header and, even if it did, it is far from ideal.

What I would ideally have, is the `<td id>` ("currentProfitAndLossAccount") followed by the corresponding value, in a list:

```
"currentProfitAndLossAccount","12,345"
"previousProfitAndLossAccount","67,890"
```

with or without separators.

There are actually about twenty fields that I am trying to collate. Then it would be an easy matter to import it into my database. I have 100k files to import, but I've been struggling for over a week getting the very first file into the right format to import.

Following help from Ronan Lopes I now have the following Ruby:

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'JSON'
require 'Pry'
require 'csv'

# this is how we request the page we're going to scrape
page = File.open("D:/Accounts.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }

#this is an empty array where we will store the output
companies_array = []

# this is where we select the data we want to isolate

page.css('nonFraction').map{|n| { n.parent.attributes["id"].value => n.text } }
```

###THIS IS THE PART THAT ISN'T WORKING, I THINK###

```
post_name = n

# the next push command appends whatever is in the brackets to the companies_array storage
    companies_array.push(post_name)

# this will push the storage into a csv file
CSV.open('D:/accounts.csv','w') do |csv|
    csv << companies_array
end
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the exact output you're waiting in that case?

Comment: Ideally, the output would be as follows:

Comment: can't read it here on comments, please update the question with that info. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have updated the question with the ideal output. Anything that I can import into a database would be fine. Once I can get this part of the code working, I should be able to leverage the rest.

Comment: Part of the problem is that your HTML/XML sample contains namespaces but your example doesn't show the namespace definition. We can work around that but the resulting code will not be directly applicable to the question or what you *should* be working with. The second problem is the `ix` tag, which isn't HTML. It could be treated as XML but without that namespace again.... The HTML is probably processed by a pre-processor on the server side which'd convert that into the actual output, but that's all guessing without the real content.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this works for all of your tables, but for that one, this can give what you want (at least it will give you the idea for the other ones):

I parsed it as a HTML instead of XML:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("D:/Accounts.xml").read)
```

And, to get the values you want:

```
page.css('nonfraction').map{|n| { n.parent.attributes["id"].value => n.text } }
```

It gives you a hash with the key/value you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are no error messages, but the final array is not collecting any data. I have added the .rb code as I have updated it, to the original question, following your advice. Please could you help me on this last part? It feels as though it is very nearly there. Thank you